# Allow only registered users to sub domain

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess

I have a subdomain that I want only registered users to access.

Each user has a domain field in the mysql database table with the subdomain name that they can access.

Right now, anyone can access my subdomains, so I want to lock it down.

What do I need to add to the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: How do users authenticate? Why do you want to use htaccess for this?

Comment: users authenticate via a login screen against a mysql table. I thought .htaccess was the way to lockout folders on a hosted server

Comment: Since you authenticate users in your application layer, access control must be handled by that layer as well. .htaccess is for the Apache layer which has not easily knowledge of your app user.

Comment: so how would i go about that? domain and subdomain are in php using sessions (). One slight issue is the subdomain has is own database with different data

Comment: You'd have to setup a central authentication service. For each application (subdomain) you can then say "Please log in or you dont see anything"

Comment: @Felix how would o go about adding this so all can communicate?

Comment: This highly depends on your application/infrastructure. LDAP could be a solution for you. If your Intention is, that users from Site A can communicate with users from Site B this would be a new question. For pure authentication/authorization I'd recommend you give LDAP a look.

Comment: @Felix Nice idea but im on a hosted web server so this may not be an option.